# Program running non-stop in ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to run non-stop program in SSH.
When I use Command `./program.out` and I close SSH my program exits too.
I'm not root.

Comment: Your process is getting a hangup signal from the pseudo-tty. Start it with the `nohup` command, or just call `signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the program 'screen' for that.

```
ssh name@server
screen
# startProgramYouWant
CTRL-A+D
# now you are in nomal shell and can exit your ssh session
# ... later
ssh name@server
screen -r
# now you are in your earlier screen session
```